# Nullpointer Exception in BroadCastService Class in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have to send an email at particular date so thats why I'm using BroadcastReceiver class.But When i run the app it getting crash and getting NullPointerException at the line =  Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);.Can someone help me please how to do this.Thanks in advance.

Here is my code

```
public class Xyz extends Activity
{
    EditText etServiceName;
    EditText etSupplierName;
    EditText etEmailId;
    EditText etReplacementDate;
    EditText etInterval_Days;
    EditText etNextReplanishmentDate;
    Button btnSubmit;

    String strServiceName;
    String strSuppliername;
    String strEmail;
    String strReplacementDate;
    String strIntervalDays;
    String strNextReplacementDate;

    String body;
    Date convertedDate;
    int interval_days;
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    int i;
    static final int DATE_OF_REPLACEMENT = 1111;
    int intConvertDays;
    String strMinusDate;
    int IntMinusDate;

    Context context;
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();

    Database_Helper databaseHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
```

etInterval_Days.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

```
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     String fixedDate = etReplacementDate.getText().toString().trim();
                     SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MM-yyyy" );
                       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                       try
                       {
                                cal.setTime( dateFormat1.parse( fixedDate ) );
                       } 
                       catch (ParseException e) 
                       {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                       }

                       String strNumDays = etInterval_Days.getText().toString().trim();
                       if(strNumDays.trim().length()>0)
                       {
                           try
                              { 
                                  intConvertDays =Integer.valueOf(strNumDays);
                              }
                              catch(NumberFormatException ne)
                              {
                                 System.out.println("could not parse :: " +ne);
                              }

                       }

                        cal.add( Calendar.DATE, intConvertDays );
                       Date dated = cal.getTime();
                       String beforDate_String = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(dated);
                       System.out.println("beforDate_String: " + beforDate_String);
                       etNextReplanishmentDate.setText(beforDate_String);

                       cal.add( Calendar.DATE, -2 );
                       Date minusDate = cal.getTime();
                       strMinusDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(minusDate);
                       System.out.println("String strMinusDate : " + strMinusDate);



                       if(strMinusDate.trim().length()>0)
                       {
                           try
                              { 
                                IntMinusDate =Integer.valueOf(strMinusDate);
                                System.out.println(" IntMinusDate = " + IntMinusDate);
                              }
                              catch(NumberFormatException ne)
                              {
                                 System.out.println("could not parse :: " +ne);
                              }

                       }
                  }
            });


         btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);
         btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 strEmail= etEmailId.getText().toString().trim();


                         strServiceName =  etServiceName.getText().toString().trim();
                         strSuppliername= etSupplierName.getText().toString().trim();
                         strReplacementDate= etReplacementDate.getText().toString().trim();
                         strIntervalDays= etInterval_Days.getText().toString().trim();
                         strNextReplacementDate = etNextReplanishmentDate.getText().toString().trim();
                         System.out.println("Data :- " + strServiceName +","+ strSuppliername +","+ strEmail +","+ strReplacementDate +","+ strIntervalDays + "," + strNextReplacementDate+" , "+strMinusDate);

                         SharedPreferences sharedPref =getSharedPreferences("MyPref_Email", 0);
                         SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = sharedPref.edit();

                         editor1.putString("ServiceName", strServiceName);
                         editor1.putString("Suppliername", strSuppliername);
                         editor1.putString("Email", strEmail);
                         editor1.putString("ReplacementDate", strReplacementDate);
                         editor1.putString("IntervalDays", strIntervalDays);
                         editor1.putString("NextReplacementDate", strNextReplacementDate);
                         editor1.putString("EmailDate", strMinusDate);

                         editor1.commit();
                         Log.e("Commit is Complit", "Save");

                         //sendEmail();
                         System.out.println("Email Has To Be Sent Successfully");

                         databaseHelper.insertServicenDetails(strServiceName, strSuppliername, strEmail, strReplacementDate, strIntervalDays, strNextReplacementDate);
                         System.out.println("Data Has Been Save Successfully");



                            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
                            long millis = 0;
                            try {
                                millis = format.parse(strMinusDate).getTime();
                                System.out.println("millis  = " + millis);
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            cal.isSet((int) millis);

                            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) Xyz.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
                            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
                            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
                            Log.d("Testing", "alarm manager set");



              }
        });




Here is AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver class
public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    String strServiceName;
    String strSuppliername;
    String strEmail;
    String strReplacementDate;
    String strIntervalDays;
    String strNextReplacementDate;
    String strEmailDate;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context con, Intent arg1)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         SharedPreferences prefs = con.getSharedPreferences("MyPref_CellNumber", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = prefs.edit();

         strServiceName=prefs.getString("ServiceName", "a/n");
         strSuppliername=prefs.getString("Suppliername" , "a/n");
         strEmail=prefs.getString("Email" , "a/n");
         strReplacementDate=prefs.getString("ReplacementDate" , "a/n");
         strIntervalDays=prefs.getString("IntervalDays" , "a/n");
         strNextReplacementDate=prefs.getString("NextReplacementDate" , "a/n");
         strEmailDate = prefs.getString("EmailDate", "a/n");

         System.out.println(strServiceName+" , "+strSuppliername+" , "+strEmail+" , "+strReplacementDate+" , "+strIntervalDays+" , "+strNextReplacementDate);

         Log.e("ON CREATE" , "=" + strServiceName);
         Log.e("ON CREATE" , "=" + strSuppliername);
         Log.e("ON CREATE" , "=" + strEmail);
         Log.e("ON CREATE" , "=" + strReplacementDate);
         Log.e("ON CREATE" , "=" + strIntervalDays);
         Log.e("ON CREATE" , "=" + strNextReplacementDate);
         Log.e("ON CREATE" , "=" + strEmailDate);


        String subject =strServiceName;

        String body = strServiceName
                      +","
                      +strSuppliername
                      +","
                      +strEmail
                      +","
                      +strReplacementDate
                      +","
                      +strIntervalDays
                      +","
                      +strNextReplacementDate
                      +","
                      +strEmailDate;

                          Log.e("body " , " = " + body);

                          Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                          i.setType("message/rfc822");
                        //  i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                          i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{strEmail});
                          i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                          i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , body);
                          con.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share viaSend mail...in Service Background"));
                          Log.e("Send Email ="," In My Service  ");
                          System.out.println("Service start time");

    }

}


Here is log cat
08-19 18:03:00.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1555): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 18:03:00.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1555): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-19 18:03:00.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
08-19 18:03:00.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:2702)
08-19 18:03:00.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at com.demo.Xyz$4.onClick(Xyz.java:282)
08-19 18:03:00.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
08-19 18:03:00.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
08-19 18:03:00.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-19 18:03:00.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-19 18:03:00.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-19 18:03:00.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-19 18:03:00.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 18:03:00.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-19 18:03:00.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-19 18:03:00.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-19 18:03:00.396: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: where is context initialized?

Comment: @ Raghunandan:- Before onCreate() method in Activity class.

Comment: @ Raghunandan:I have post updated code please see above.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have initialized contet before `onCreate()` method in Activity class.

In fact from the posted code context is just declared never initialized.

```
Context context; // declared
```

Context is available once activity in created. In `onCreate` initialize context.

In onCreate

```
Context context;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
   context = this; 
   ...// rest of the code
```

Edit:

```
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   i.setType("message/rfc822");
   i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{strEmail});
   i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
   i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , body);
   i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   con.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share viaSend mail...in Service Background"));
```

Comment: I initialize Context context = null; Still getting null pointer exception .

Comment: @Robotics  `context = null;`??. what do you expect to happen when `context = null`. Just follow the post again.

Comment: Sorry ,I using this keyword but still getting error like =  08-19 18:24:26.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1626): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.demo.AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: @Robotics that is a new problem it has nothing to with the first problem posted Just set a flad as stated in the exception. Note: startActivity is method of activity

Comment: @Roboticsjust do `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` and it should work

Comment: :-From two days I'm trying but unfortunately I'm not finding any solution for how to send email on particular date automatically.

Comment: @Robotics now that is too broad a question for stackoverflow. Is the current problem sovled.

Comment: @Robotics you haven't followed my suggestion. So how do you expect the error to be gone. Pls check the edited post again. read the error that itself is self explanatory.

Comment: Thank you so much I have solved the problem myself.Thanks for the replay.

Comment: @ Raghunandan : Not the above help, but thank you for the help.

Comment: @Robotics why not the above. it will work AFAIK. if not your problem might be something else. Also looking at your posts your questions lack clarity. No this but a few of your other questions

Comment: :- I have changed coding in my own way like this =    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
               shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
               shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
               shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{strEmail});
               shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , body);
 Intent new_intent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via");
new_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
con.startActivity(new_intent);

Comment: @Robotics is this `shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` not same as mine which is `i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` the rest of the code is not related to the current question asked. That is what you error says  Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want? Is it not??